# How to retrieve imagepath from arraylist & display them in gridview?

Tags: android, image, sqlite

I have taken the  two different paths of images are stored in sdcard.I want to display the both images in gridview.Can you please help me?The main problem is that if i am using arraylist of integer type and giving the ids of image than i can see the image but if i am using the arraylist of string type which have the path of image than how to show the image.
i also commented over the line where to change,please help me??

```
    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter 
    {
        private Context mContext;

         public ImageAdapter(Context c) 
        {
          mContext = c;    
         }

       public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
     }

     public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

//here i am getting problem tell me how to use path of image in arraylist

    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        return imageView;
    }

    // references to our images    
ArrayList<String> mThumbIds=new ArrayList<String>;
mThumbIds.add("/mnt/sdcard/a.jpg");
mThumbIds.add("/mnt/sdcard/b.jpg");
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set image path directly with `setImageResource()`. Instead try:

```
Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mThumbIds[position]);
imageview.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
```